# What's holding up my PHP script?

Tags: php, performance, apache, web-crawler

We've got a PHP crawler running on our web server. When the crawler is running, there are no cpu, memory or network bandwidth spikes. Everything is normal. But our website (also PHP), hosted on the same server, stops responding. Basically the crawler blocks any other php script from running.

EDIT:

** fsockopen is being used to download files to crawler! **

Comment: From the information you give, it could be anything. Anything at all. Is there any information you could offer that might narrow this down? As it is, I don't know whether to vote-to-close as 'not a real question' (I don't know how to begin to work out what the problem is, let alone how to address/resolve it), or 'migrate-to-serverfault.' We *need* more information, but I don't even know what to ask for.

Comment: Well, let me try making it simpler. One php script keeps running continuously in the background. Until that script is stopped, no other php script can run on the server.

Comment: this is like looking for needles in a haystack and the haystack is as tall as the eiffel tower. please check the crawler and let us know if it uses fsockopen, or libcurl, or show some code re: file locking, source/destination TCP ports. Could be that the crawler is just doing an endless loop. Have you checked CPU utilization?

Comment: fsockopen is being used to download files to crawler!

Comment: After you open a connection with fsockopen, do you also close the connection? A typical webserver can only have a couple of hundreds of connections open at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look into the error.log file?

Comment: There are no outstanding errors. The crawler otherwise works fine. The website works fine when the crawler is not running. But the website stops responding when the crawler starts running.